# Redis and massive parallel incrementation

Tags: python, redis, sparse-matrix

I am writing a python software that builds a sparse matrix. Its size can be from 10.000 x 10.000 to 30.000 x 30.000. As of now I do it with scipy.sparse but it's quite difficult because I want to build it in a multi-process way.

As of now I have one process that that send data to worker processes, and a "matrix process" that receive the cells to increment from the workers (I don't want to duplicate the matrix in each work process).

Well...let's say I'm not satisfied.

I though to use Redis to store the sparse matrix, and calling "INC 2:3" to increment the cell (2,3). Then when all worker have finished, I can retrieve the matrix by retrieving all the keys in order to construct the scipy.sparse (the cells which value are egal to 0 won't have any key).

To construct a matrix it needs something like 500.000.000.000 inc operations, and something like 30 worker processes. Well this is an upper bound as it will also be used for smaller computations, like 45.000.000 inc operations and 3 workers.

Do you think Redis will be better than scipy.sparse for this work ? Or do you have any other suggestion ?

Thanks !

Comment: Consider having each worker calculate a part of the sparse matrix, then a "joiner" worker merging each sparse matrix into a (also sparse) larger matrix.  Using 'multiprocessing' means you can do multiple CPU-bound things in parallel, and operate directly on matrices vs going back and forth with Redis INC commands.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: The old version of the software worked liked that. Unfortunately, the "joining" is way too slow.

Comment: Have you looked into the [`HYPERLOGLOG`](http://redis.io/commands/pfcount) feature of redis? It depends on the usecase, statistics involved here. However, very fast.